# Running H2O with Java 16 on R

Tags: java, r, h2o

I installed "h2o" using the R command `install.packages("h2o")`.  This prompted me to install the latest version of Java, which I did: version 16.  All ran perfectly – except that on launch, h2o would nag me to install the latest version of h2o from the h2o.ai website, as the version packaged with the CRAN download is 5 months out of date.

When I downloaded h2o version 3.32.0.5, I was unable to start h2o with `h2o.init()`: I receive the message "only Java 8...14 are supported, system version is 16".

Java 14 is listed as having security flaws, so I'd rather not downgrade from Java 16; instead, I'd like to revert to the previous version of h2o (as installed from CRAN).  I uninstalled Java and the h2o R package completely, then reinstalled Java 16 and ran `install.packages("h2o")`: but I still see the "only Java 8-14 supported" message.  How can I get h2o running again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry about this.  We are working to improve this process.  Please see this [ticket](https://h2oai.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-8053) and feel free to provide your feedback here or on the ticket.

> This prompted me to install the latest version of Java, which I did: version 16.

Can you explain where H2O prompted you to update your Java?  Are you sure it was not asking you to just update your version of H2O?

H2O does not yet support Java 16 and our next release (coming out very shortly) has official support for Java 15.  If you want to install Java 15, then you can use a [nightly](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/master/latest.html) version of H2O until our next stable release comes out in the next few days.

Comment: Thanks! The 'update to latest java' message appears with a link in the startup messages triggered by R command `library('h2o')` when Java is not installed.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying -- we will clean up that message too to be more clear.  The new stable release of H2O, v3.32.1.1 (released a few days ago) now officially supports Java 15.  You can download the latest stable at this link: http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable.html